# how to use str.format() with variables in python

Tags: python

I am wanting to use str.format() with the variable `randomOne`, since `%s` doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
print('The number generated between %s and %s is' + number) % (randomOne, randomTwo)
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'nonetype' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: You have three separate problems here: First, `str.format` doesn't use `%s` placeholders, it uses `{}` placeholders. Second, you're not actually calling `str.format`, you're using the `%` operator. And finally, you're using the operator on the result of `print`-ing the string, rather than on the string you wanted to print. @sweeneyrod's answer fixes all three (in two different ways, depending on whether you actually wanted `str.format` as you said, or `%` as your code showed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the formatting operation on the string, not the operation of printing the string. That is the cause of your current problem. If you want to use `str.format` in this case you would do this:

```
print('The number generated between {} and {} is {}'.format(randomOne, randomTwo, number))
```

In the event you want to stick with old style string formatting (which I wouldn't advice), you would do this:

```
print('The number generated between %s and %s is %s' % (randomOne, randomTwo, number))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the brackets at the right place

```
print('The number generated between %s and %s is %d' % (randomOne, randomTwo, number))
```